# Error in datatype (nvarchar instead of ntext)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, ssis

I am importing data from excel(.xls) to SQL Server 2008 using SSIS. I have included `IMEX=1` in the connection string of excel connection manager. But a column consists of a value as below:

```
4-Hour Engineer Dispatch ASPP Engr Dispatch 1: Up to 1 dispatch (8 hours) per year.  Hours exceeding allocation billed @ 1.5x hourly rate w/ 8-hr min Engr Dispatch:  8-hrs to arrive on-site from Ciena's determination of need  On-Site Engineer Dispatch - 8 Hour ASPP Engr Dispatch 8: Up to 8 dispatch (64 hours) per year.  Hours exceeding allocation billed @ 1.5x hourly rate w/ 8-hr min Engr Dispatch:  NBD to dispatch from Ciena's determination of need Per Incident On Site Support ASPP Engr Dispatch 12: Up to 12 dispatch (96 hours) per year.  Hours exceeding allocation billed @ 1.5x hourly rate w/ 8-hr min Engr Dispatch:  Next day to arrive on-site from Ciena's determination of need  Resident Engineer Engr Dispatch:  2-hrs to arrive on-site from Ciena's determination of need Engr Dispatch:  4-hrs to arrive on-site from Ciena's determination of need ASPP Engr Dispatch 2: Up to 2 dispatch (16 hours) per year.  Hours exceeding allocation billed @ 1.5x hourly rate w/ 8-hr min N
```

Actually there are about 600 rows in that Excel file. But the above mentioned value is present after 450 rows only. So, the datatype of that column is taken as `nvarchar(255)` as default instead of `ntext` and so I am getting error.

Anybody please help out... Thanks in advance...

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, you shouldn't be using `NTEXT` at all - use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. Actually the datatype is automatically predicted by SSIS. Also when I put the row value mentioned above as the first row, the datatype is assigned as nText. But I need the datatype to be assigned as nText automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel uses, by default, the first 8 lines to determine the data type.

You can increase the sampling size in the registry (http://ddkonline.blogspot.ca/2008/05/ssis-excel-data-source-error-text-was.html)

Beware, it seems that this key is not always located there. On my machine, it was located in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel`.

You can search for `TypeGuessRows` in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS use Basic Data Flow Transformations\Data Conversion between Excel Source and OLE DB Destination

[**Example**](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/10/01/data-conversion-in-ssis.aspx)